# Justifying ('ragged right/left, center') all the tables in a document

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Suppose I want to left justify all my tables to a certain vertical line (MWE):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{changepage}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Sans}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Mono}

\newcommand{\leftpadding}{1cm}

\begin{document}

    \chapter{}

    All Gaul is divided into three parts, one of which the Belgae inhabit, the Aquitani another, those who in their own language are called Celts, in our Gauls, the third. All these differ from each other in language, customs and laws. The river Garonne separates the Gauls from the Aquitani; the Marne and the Seine separate them from the Belgae. 

    \medskip\begin{adjustwidth}{\leftpadding}{0cm}
        \raggedright{Caption}\\
        \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
        \footnotesize\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}

            \hline
            {Alfa}
            & {Bravo}
            \\\hline

            {Charlie}
            & {Delta}
            \\\hline

        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustwidth}

    \bigskip
    Of all these, the Belgae are the bravest, because they are furthest from the civilization and refinement of [our] Province, and merchants least frequently resort to them, and import those things which tend to effeminate the mind.

    \medskip\begin{adjustwidth}{\leftpadding}{0cm}
        \raggedright{Another Caption}\\
        \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
        \footnotesize\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}

            \hline
            {Longer Echo}
            & {Long Foxtrot}
            \\\hline

            {Golf}
            & {Hotel}
            \\\hline

        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustwidth}

    \bigskip
    They are the nearest to the Germans, who dwell beyond the Rhine, with whom they are continually waging war; for which reason the Helvetii also surpass the rest of the Gauls in valor.

\end{document}
```

This solution works, but I want more flexibility. How, for instance, am I to redefine `\leftpadding` to center all the tables at once? It should be possible, at least in two passes. The option of right justifying wouldn't hurt, too. Entirely different solutions to the same purpose are also welcome.

Comment: You shouldn't use `\raggedright{Caption}` since then you can't label and reference those tables.

Comment: I shouldn't, yes. First things first, though. I'm in search for a good, LaTeX way solution.

Comment: I don't quite get what you want. Do you want the tables only to be indented on the left but take the full width to the right in the first case? And when centered, should they be able to obtain the whole width but just centered? And for right-aligned, should they be indented from the right margin and take the full width? All the above for both, the caption and the tabular? What if the entered tabular is too wide for the defined spacing? etc.

Comment: No, I want them to stay as wide as they are. Yes, I want the tables indented from the left margin as in the MWE, or from the right margin, or centered. All of the above by changing one definition (presumably `\leftpadding`). The captions are to follow suit gracefully. All the tables are presumed no wider then the text width.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Though I don't quite get what you want, here is a solution (which hopefully fits your needs) using the `pgfkeys`-package. I made the captions in a way, that they can be labeled (using the `label=` key) but they don't use the `\caption` command internally. Also it doesn't use your command `\leftpadding` but the `padding`-key.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{changepage}

%\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Serif}
%\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Sans}
%\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Mono}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@placedleft
\newif\if@placedright
\newif\if@placedmiddle
\newif\if@placedcapused
\newif\if@placedscapused
\newif\if@placedlabused
\newdimen\@placedpadding
\newdimen\@placedrest
\pgfkeys{/placedt/.is family,/placedt,
    default/.style={% change the default settings here
        place=left,
        stretch=1.4,
        padding=1cm,
    },
    stretch/.estore in=\arraystretch,
    place/.is choice,
        place/left/.code=\@placedlefttrue\@placedrightfalse\@placedmiddlefalse,
        place/right/.code=\@placedrighttrue\@placedleftfalse\@placedmiddlefalse,
        place/middle/.code=\@placedmiddletrue\@placedleftfalse\@placedrightfalse,
    padding/.estore in=\@placedpadding,
    caption/.code=\@placedcapusedtrue\def\@placedcap{#1},
    scaption/.code=\@placedscapusedtrue\def\@placedscap{#1},
    label/.code=\@placedlabusedtrue\def\@placedlab{#1},
}

\newenvironment{placedtabular}[2][]{%
    \par\medskip\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
        \pgfkeys{/placedt, default, #1}%
        \if@placedleft%
            \@placedrest=\textwidth%
            \advance\@placedrest by -\@placedpadding%
            \hskip\@placedpadding%
            \begin{minipage}{\@placedrest}%
                \raggedright%
        \else\if@placedmiddle%
            \centering%
        \else\if@placedright%
            \@placedrest=\textwidth%
            \advance\@placedrest by -\@placedpadding%
            \begin{minipage}{\@placedrest}%
                \raggedleft%
        \fi\fi\fi%
        \if@placedcapused%
            \refstepcounter{table}%
            \tablename~\thetable: \@placedcap%
            \if@placedscapused%
                \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\@placedscap}%
            \else%
                \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\@placedcap}%
            \fi%
            \if@placedlabused%
                \label{\@placedlab}%
            \fi%
            \\[0.2\baselineskip]%
        \fi%
        \footnotesize\begin{tabular}{#2}%
    }{
        \end{tabular}%
        \if@placedmiddle\else%
            \end{minipage}%
        \fi%
    \end{minipage}%
    }
\makeatother

\newcommand{\leftpadding}{1cm}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

    \chapter{}

    All Gaul is divided into three parts, one of which the Belgae inhabit, the Aquitani another, those who in their own language are called Celts, in our Gauls, the third. All these differ from each other in language, customs and laws. The river Garonne separates the Gauls from the Aquitani; the Marne and the Seine separate them from the Belgae. 

    \begin{placedtabular}[caption=Caption,label=tab:first]{|c|c|}
            \hline
            {Alfa}
            & {Bravo}
            \\\hline

            {Charlie}
            & {Delta}
            \\\hline
    \end{placedtabular}

    \medskip\begin{adjustwidth}{\leftpadding}{0cm}
        \raggedright{Caption}\\
        \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
        \footnotesize\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}

            \hline
            {Alfa}
            & {Bravo}
            \\\hline

            {Charlie}
            & {Delta}
            \\\hline

        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustwidth}

    \bigskip
    Of all these, the Belgae are the bravest, because they are furthest from the civilization and refinement of [our] Province, and merchants least frequently resort to them, and import those things which tend to effeminate the mind.

    \begin{placedtabular}[caption=Another Caption,label=tab:second]{|c|c|}
            \hline
            {Longer Echo}
            & {Long Foxtrot}
            \\\hline

            {Golf}
            & {Hotel}
            \\\hline
    \end{placedtabular}
    \medskip\begin{adjustwidth}{\leftpadding}{0cm}
        \raggedright{Another Caption}\\
        \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
        \footnotesize\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}

            \hline
            {Longer Echo}
            & {Long Foxtrot}
            \\\hline

            {Golf}
            & {Hotel}
            \\\hline

        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustwidth}

    \bigskip
    They are the nearest to the Germans, who dwell beyond the Rhine, with whom they are continually waging war; for which reason the Helvetii also surpass the rest of the Gauls in valor.

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Note that I have slightly altered the above code.

Usage of the `placedtabular`-environment is just like a normal `tabular` except, that in the optional argument you can use a comma seperated `key=value` syntax. The following keys are alailable:

- `stretch`: the value used for `arraystretch`
- `place`: the placement of the table. Available are `left`, `right` and `middle`
- `padding`: the space to the left or right margin with `place=left` or `place=right`, respectively
- `caption`: the caption used for the table
- `scaption`: the table-name for the `\listoftables`, if not used `caption` is used. If `caption` is not used, this doesn't have any effect.
- `label`: the label used for referencing the table

When you use one of these keys in a `placedtabular`-environment, the effects are only local and don't affect any other table set with this environment.

From the aforementioned keys `place`, `stretch` and `padding` have a default value, which are set in between the brackets of `default/.style={...}` which is used inside the first call of `\pgfkeys` in the above MWE. There is also the comment 'change the default settings here'.

EDIT2: The below code is everything inbetween of `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` and doesn't set 'table x.y' infront of the caption. Because of this, I also removed the `label`-key as referencing won't work with this.

```
\makeatletter
\newif\if@placedleft
\newif\if@placedright
\newif\if@placedmiddle
\newif\if@placedcapused
\newif\if@placedscapused
%\newif\if@placedlabused
\newdimen\@placedpadding
\newdimen\@placedrest
\pgfkeys{/placedt/.is family,/placedt,
    default/.style={%
        place=left,
        stretch=1.4,
        padding=1cm,
    },
    stretch/.estore in=\arraystretch,
    place/.is choice,
        place/left/.code=\@placedlefttrue\@placedrightfalse\@placedmiddlefalse,
        place/right/.code=\@placedrighttrue\@placedleftfalse\@placedmiddlefalse,
        place/middle/.code=\@placedmiddletrue\@placedleftfalse\@placedrightfalse,
    padding/.estore in=\@placedpadding,
    caption/.code=\@placedcapusedtrue\def\@placedcap{#1},
    scaption/.code=\@placedscapusedtrue\def\@placedscap{#1},
}

\newenvironment{placedtabular}[2][]{%
    \par\medskip\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
        \pgfkeys{/placedt, default, #1}%
        \if@placedleft%
            \@placedrest=\textwidth%
            \advance\@placedrest by -\@placedpadding%
            \hskip\@placedpadding%
            \begin{minipage}{\@placedrest}%
                \raggedright%
        \else\if@placedmiddle%
            \centering%
        \else\if@placedright%
            \@placedrest=\textwidth%
            \advance\@placedrest by -\@placedpadding%
            \begin{minipage}{\@placedrest}%
                \raggedleft%
        \fi\fi\fi%
        \if@placedcapused%
            \@placedcap%
            \if@placedscapused%
                \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\@placedscap}%
            \else%
                \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\@placedcap}%
            \fi%
            \\[0.2\baselineskip]%
        \fi%
        \footnotesize\begin{tabular}{#2}%
  }{
      \end{tabular}%
      \if@placedmiddle\else%
          \end{minipage}%
      \fi%
  \end{minipage}%
  }
```

\makeatother

EDIT3: Complete code (without `label` and without the `Table x.y:` prefix) which includes two more options:

- `font` are fontswitches applied to the table (stuff like `\bfseries`, `\footnotesize` or `\small`)
- `captionfont` are fontswitches applied to the caption

Both have the default to no change to surrounding fontswitches. If used both reset size and font and apply the argument provided.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}

\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{changepage}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Sans}
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-text]{Liberation Mono}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\makeatletter
\newif\if@placedleft
\newif\if@placedright
\newif\if@placedmiddle
\newif\if@placedcapused
\newif\if@placedscapused
\newif\if@placedfontused
\newif\if@placedcfontused
\newdimen\@placedpadding
\newdimen\@placedrest
\pgfkeys{/placedt/.is family,/placedt,
    default/.style={%
        place=left,
        stretch=1.4,
        padding=1cm,
    },
    stretch/.estore in=\arraystretch,
    place/.is choice,
        place/left/.code=\@placedlefttrue\@placedrightfalse\@placedmiddlefalse,
        place/right/.code=\@placedrighttrue\@placedleftfalse\@placedmiddlefalse,
        place/middle/.code=\@placedmiddletrue\@placedleftfalse\@placedrightfalse,
    padding/.estore in=\@placedpadding,
    caption/.code=\@placedcapusedtrue\def\@placedcap{#1},
    scaption/.code=\@placedscapusedtrue\def\@placedscap{#1},
    font/.store in=\@placedfont,
    captionfont/.store in=\@placedcapfont,
    font/.code=\@placedfontusedtrue\def\@placedfont{#1},
    captionfont/.code=\@placedcfontusedtrue\def\@placedcapfont{#1},
}

\newenvironment{placedtabular}[2][]{%
    \par\medskip\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
        \pgfkeys{/placedt, default, #1}%
        \if@placedleft%
            \@placedrest=\textwidth%
            \advance\@placedrest by -\@placedpadding%
            \hskip\@placedpadding%
            \begin{minipage}{\@placedrest}%
                \raggedright%
        \else\if@placedmiddle%
            \centering%
        \else\if@placedright%
            \@placedrest=\textwidth%
            \advance\@placedrest by -\@placedpadding%
            \begin{minipage}{\@placedrest}%
                \raggedleft%
        \fi\fi\fi%
        \if@placedcapused%
            {\if@placedcfontused\normalsize\normalfont\@placedcapfont\fi\@placedcap}%
            \if@placedscapused%
                \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\@placedscap}%
            \else%
                \addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\@placedcap}%
            \fi%
            \\[0.2\baselineskip]%
        \fi%
        \if@placedfontused\normalsize\normalfont\@placedfont\fi%
        \begin{tabular}{#2}%
    }{
        \end{tabular}%
        \if@placedmiddle\else%
            \end{minipage}%
        \fi%
    \end{minipage}%
    }
\makeatother

\newcommand{\leftpadding}{1cm}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

    \chapter{}

    All Gaul is divided into three parts, one of which the Belgae inhabit, the Aquitani another, those who in their own language are called Celts, in our Gauls, the third. All these differ from each other in language, customs and laws. The river Garonne separates the Gauls from the Aquitani; the Marne and the Seine separate them from the Belgae. 

    \begin{placedtabular}[caption=Caption,font=\bfseries]{|c|c|}
            \hline
            {Alfa}
            & {Bravo}
            \\\hline

            {Charlie}
            & {Delta}
            \\\hline
    \end{placedtabular}

    \medskip\begin{adjustwidth}{\leftpadding}{0cm}
        \raggedright{Caption}\\
        \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
        \footnotesize\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}

            \hline
            {Alfa}
            & {Bravo}
            \\\hline

            {Charlie}
            & {Delta}
            \\\hline

        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustwidth}

    \bigskip
    Of all these, the Belgae are the bravest, because they are furthest from the civilization and refinement of [our] Province, and merchants least frequently resort to them, and import those things which tend to effeminate the mind.

    \begin{placedtabular}[caption={Another\protect\\Caption}]{|c|c|}
            \hline
            {Longer Echo}
            & {Long Foxtrot}
            \\\hline

            {Golf}
            & {Hotel}
            \\\hline
    \end{placedtabular}
    \begin{placedtabular}[caption=Another Caption]{|c|c|}
            \hline
            {Longer Echo}
            & {Long Foxtrot}
            \\\hline

            {Golf}
            & {Hotel}
            \\\hline
    \end{placedtabular}
    \medskip\begin{adjustwidth}{\leftpadding}{0cm}
        \raggedright{Another Caption}\\
        \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
        \footnotesize\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|c|}

            \hline
            {Longer Echo}
            & {Long Foxtrot}
            \\\hline

            {Golf}
            & {Hotel}
            \\\hline

        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustwidth}

    \bigskip
    They are the nearest to the Germans, who dwell beyond the Rhine, with whom they are continually waging war; for which reason the Helvetii also surpass the rest of the Gauls in valor.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks exactly the real thing so far, thanks! It takes some grokking, though. Meanwhile, would you be so kind as to supply centered and right justified (0.5cm, say, from the right margin) usages of the `placedtabular` environment? It is not obvious, at least to me :) .

Comment: I got it! The `place` is either `left`, or `middle` or `right`. The only problem left: how am I supposed to get rid of `Table x.y:` prefix? The prefix is a good thing, but I don't want it for a particular document.

Comment: Thank you very much for an exhaustive answer! It's more than expected.

Comment: This is curious. I accepted. I've got a green check with a tooltip `Click to undoo acceptance...`. It's nothing short of a gem of a perfect answer, robust and debugged :) . Now that you mention things missing: how am I supposed to break the caption into two or more lines? `\\\\` messes things up (though break them it does).

Comment: 16 hours ago, the tooltip says.

Comment: Oh, now the answer is accepted. Well, there are two options for inserting linebreaks into the caption: 1) insert it like this `\protect\\ `. 2) remove the lines which state `\addcontentsline{lot}{table}{...}` in the definition of the environment. If you don't plan to use a 'list of tables' they are not necessary anyway. The issue is caused, because macros like `\\ ` are not allowed in the contents of such lists (there are others as well) and need to be protected. Google what `\protect` does for a better explanation.

Comment: `\footnotesize` got hardwired into the `placedtabular` definition. I want it optional, too. Pretty please.

Comment: See my edit. You should try to understand the code (it's not that cryptic) so you can apply small changes yourself, though.

Comment: Thanks! Meanwhile I've made a kludge, something like `\if... \normalsize\begin{tabular}... \else... \footnotesize\begin{tabular}... \fi`. I've not managed to glue `...size` directly to `\begin{tabular}...`. Now I'm troubled with `error: line 2996 TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [semantic nest size=500]` :) . Inside `placedtabular` environment which previously compiled somehow. The document is fairly big, over 7000 lines.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, Skillmon. My kludge probably has done something lethal to the compilation stack. Your update again works flawlessly. I'm ready to dive into `pgfmanual`, which is about one thousand pages long...

Comment: Well I've only read the parts concerning pgfkeys (chapter 82) but not completely. I generate plots with python's matplotlib and export them as pgf at the moment. But the pgfmanual is on my list :)

Comment: It seems that the `/.code` makes the `/.store in` useless though...? (come across this one while researching for [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/650209/250119))

Comment: @user202729 yep, this is what happens if you evolve code over time without clean-ups :)