# Pgfkeys .code and \directlua problem

Tags: pgfkeys, directlua

Comment the 2 lines alternativelly, one works the other doesn't :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/Baq/.cd ,
    nb/.default = 10,
    nb/.store in = \nb,
    nb,
    contraintes/.default = 5,
    contraintes/.store in = \contraintes,

%       Comment alternativelly
    contraintes/.code={\directlua{contraintes = \contraintes }} ,

    contraintes
}

\newcommand{\Contraintes}[1][contraintes = 6]{%
\pgfkeys{/Baq/.cd , #1 }
\directlua{

%       Comment alternativelly
%       contraintes = \contraintes

    nb = \nb
    
    tex. print ( "Coucou :" , \nb , \contraintes )
}
}

\begin{frame}

\Contraintes

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It is possible to make the `\directlua` command part to work, but hen one can't change the value :

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/Baq/.cd ,
    contraintes/.store in = \contraintes,
    contraintes = 5,
    contraintes/.code={\directlua{contraintes = \contraintes }} ,
}

\newcommand{\Contraintes}[1][contraintes = 6]{%
\pgfkeys{/Baq/.cd , #1 }
\directlua{
    tex. print ( "Coucou :" , \contraintes )
}
}

\begin{frame}

\Contraintes

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `/.initial` and `/.code` (or one of its relatives) can be used to bind to a key both a value and some code, respectively. See the [doc for `/.initial`](https://tikz.dev/pgfkeys#pgf./handlers/.initial).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue is that `.store in` and `.code` cannot be used at the same time. (because `store in` is also a `code`, so the second one overrides the first one, I think? [What is the fundamental difference between .store in and .code in pgfkeys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299315/what-is-the-fundamental-difference-between-store-in-and-code-in-pgfkeys))

Either way, you can do the "store in" manually inside the "code":

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{/Baq/.cd ,
    nb/.default = 10,
    nb/.store in = \nb,
    nb,
    contraintes/.default = 5,
    contraintes/.code={\def\contraintes{#1}\directlua{contraintes = \contraintes}} ,
    contraintes
}

\newcommand{\Contraintes}[1][contraintes = 6]{%
\pgfkeys{/Baq/.cd , #1 }
\directlua{
    nb = \nb
    tex. print ( "Coucou :" , \nb , \contraintes )
}
}

\begin{frame}

\Contraintes

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (I can't find any question so far that combine `store in` and `code` although it *seems* to be a common thing. Closest is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85637/how-to-submit-a-set-of-tikz-command-with-pgfkeys although in that case OP comment it out